# Getting "error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol referenced in function _main" on VScode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I was practising a LinkedList implementation in Visual Studio and the code **runs fine in Visual Studio**. But since I use vscode most of the time I followed [this tutorial from official vscode website](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc). the demo code form the given link builds and runs successfully without any error or warning. but when I try to build my LinkedList c++ project I get errors for each function and the build exits. The errors are given below

```
LinkedList.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall 

List::List(void)" (??0List@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
LinkedList.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall List::addNode(int)" (?addNode@List@@QAEXH@Z) referenced in function _main
LinkedList.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall List::deleteNode(int)" (?deleteNode@List@@QAEXH@Z) referenced in function _main
LinkedList.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall List::printList(void)" (?printList@List@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function _main
```

I don't actually know where I am making the mistake since this is the first time I am trying to run C++ codes on VScode. my CPP, header and Driver files are given below.

**List.h**

```
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H

class List {
private:
    typedef struct node {
        int data;
        node* next;
    }*nodePtr;

    nodePtr head;
    nodePtr current;
    nodePtr temp;

public:
    List();
    void addNode(int addData);
    void deleteNode(int delData);
    void printList();
};

#endif
```

**List.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

#include "List.h"

using namespace std;

List::List() {
    head = NULL;
    current = NULL;
    temp = NULL;
}

void List::addNode(int addData) {
    nodePtr n = new node;
    n->next = NULL;
    n->data = addData;

    if (head != NULL) {
        current = head;

        while (current->next != NULL) {
            current = current->next;
        }
        current->next = n;
    }

    else head = n;
}
void List::deleteNode(int delData) {
    nodePtr delPtr = NULL;
    temp = head;
    current = head;

    while (current != NULL && current->data != delData) {
        temp = current;
        current = current->next;
    }

    if (current == NULL) {
        cout << delData << " not found.\n";
        delete delPtr;
    }

    /**/
    else {
        delPtr = current;
        current = current->next;
        temp->next = current;
        if (delPtr == head) {
            head = head->next;
        }
        delete delPtr;
        cout << delData << " was deleted.\n";
    }
}

void List::printList() {
    if (head == NULL) {
        cout << "list is empty";
    }

    else {
        current = head;
        while (current != NULL) {
            cout << current->data << endl;
            current = current->next;
        }
    }
}
```

**LinkedList.cpp**

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include "List.h"
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    List demo;
    demo.addNode(6);
    demo.addNode(12);
    demo.addNode(45);
    demo.addNode(67);
    demo.printList();

    demo.deleteNode(6);
    demo.deleteNode(12);
    demo.printList();
}
```

It would be great if someone could point out where I am making the mistake. I don't really want to open heavy apps like Visual Studio to practice my codes. TIA.

Comment: I think you are not linking the implementation of `Link`. The compile command would help debug this. (i.e. `tasks.json`)

Comment: You are not compiling `List.cpp`. The tutorial is good for one-source-file programs. You have something more complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As neither of the current "Answers" are applicable (One is wrong and the other is very bad practice leading to similar errors later on), here is a solution.

Disclaimer: I generally use CMake to create the builds for me meaning I am unfamiliar as to how to do this in VSCode, so this is an unoptimal way of doing it. (The reason is that in this solution all files are compiled at the same time, meaning that any time you change any file, you have to recompile all files, rather than recompiling the changed file and linking again.)

If you have all files in a dir like:

```
project_root/
- List.h
- List.cpp
- LinkedList.cpp
```

Then you can use:

```json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "shell",
      "label": "cl.exe build active file",
      "command": "cl.exe",
      "args": [
        "/Zi",
        "/EHsc",
        "/Fe:",
        "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
        "project_root/*.cpp"
      ],
      "problemMatcher": ["$msCompile"],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And that should in theory work.

Example as to what the error is:

Lets say you have:

```cpp
----------------  B.h  ---------------------
// Omitted ifndef guard
void addOne(int&);
---------------- B.cpp ---------------------
void addOne(int& addTo){
    ++addTo;
}
---------------- A.cpp ---------------------
#include "B.h"

int main(){
    int a = 0;
    addOne(a);
    return a;
}
```

Now the compiler is given the task of converting `A.cpp` into "machine code". First it executes preprocessor directives (in this case pasiting the contents of `B.h` to the top of `A.cpp`) converting `A.cpp` to:

```cpp
void addOne(int&);

void main(){
    int a = 0;
    addOne(a);
    return a;
}
```

And after this it compiles it. The compiler doesn't know what `addOne` does. All it knows is what it looks like (takes one `int&` argument and returns `void`). After the compiler is finished generating the "machine code", the linker takes control, which gets the task: Put everything together so that it makes sense. The "machine code" does not have all the things it needs to run, so the linker resolves references (i.e. it sees that you pass it two of the object files (generated by the compiler). One references `void addOne(int&)`, but never implements it, and the other merely implements it.). It then packages them into an executable, that you can run.

The reason why there are unresolved references is because `List.cpp` is not compiled, and not passed to the linker, therefore it can not find how to run functions declared in `List.cpp`.

Note if you want to go with `#include "List.cpp"` "solution" you can, BUT then it would be beneficial to declare everything in `List.cpp` to have `static` linkage, otherwise you might have the opposite error later (i.e. multiple definitions of the same thing).

Comment: thanks for your help. I made it work following your suggestions.

Comment: Thank you. Reason was in cmake, as you said. Modifying CMakeLists.txt fixed the error for me. Added new cpp file here: "add_executable(project single_entry_point.cpp static_method.cpp)".

Answer (score 0):

Link the lost libs after `#include` (beware `#pragma` only in msvc, gcc would get error)

```cpp
#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "xxx.lib")
...
```

1. Search the specific function in error, I get `<winuser.h>`
2. ask for GPT, I get `user32.lib`